# Using a non static variable on a static method through an object? Java

Tags: java, object, methods, static, non-static

Since we can't use `this` inside a static method, and we also cannot use non-static variables, why is it that we can use objects, which use nonstatic variables inside static methods?

Here is what I mean:

```
public int x;
public int y;

public Account(int a, int b) {
    this.x = a;
    this.y = b;
}

public static void Swap(Account acc) {
    int holder;
    holder = acc.x;
    acc.x = acc.y;
    acc.y = holder;
}
```

So `Swap()` will work, even though the variables inside of the object are not static. I don't understand this part. Would appreciate some help. TIA!

Comment: a potential reason I could think of is, only the initial input is important, so if the parameter is an object, and it essentially "passes" through the first check (static/non static), the rest is unimportant. Again, not sure so that's the reason I'm asking.

Comment: Think about it: what's the difference between accessing `x` and accessing `acc.x`? What is the variable that Java would prevent you from referencing if it were not static? Is `acc` static?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static` methods cannot access instance variable of the current (`this`) instance, since no such instance exists in their context.

However, if you pass to them a reference to an instance, they can access any instance variables and methods visible to them.

In case of your `swap` example, if that method wasn't `static`, you could have removed the `acc` argument and operate on the instance variables of `this`:

```
public void swap() {
    int holder;
    holder = this.x;
    this.x = this.y;
    this.y = holder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, so my assumption was correct? It essentially "checks" if that input is a static/non static primitive type, and if it isn't, it runs as long as its a reference type. Which then references to non static attributes. The lecturer explained that its a convention to implement swap as static because it doesn't really store anything inside the object..

Comment: @user472288 If by "input" you mean the argument to your swap method, that argument cannot be static (it's always a local variable by definition) so there's nothing to check. As long as it's a reference type (i.e. not a primitive type), you have access to all of its visible instance variables and methods.

Comment: Got it. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `this` in a static method because **Java does not know which instance (which this) you refer to.**

You can pass a reference to an object as a parameter `acc` to a static method because the caller specifies which instance to pass.

Java knows which instance you mean when your static method refers to `acc`. So you can use any accessible fields or methods of `acc`.